# How to use nested component variables in vue inline templates?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-blade

I have something like this in a blade template which I'm populating with Laravel backend:

```
<component-1 inline-template>
    <child-component-1 v-show='comps.cc1'></child-component-1>
    <child-component-2>
        <grandchild-component-1 v-show='subComps.cc1></grandchild-component-1>
        <grandchild-component-2 v-show='subComps.cc2></grandchild-component-2>
    </child-component-2>
</component-1>
```

the **comps** object is referencing to a variable from **component-1** and that's ok, but **subComps** object is trying to reference a variable from **component-1** as well and I want it to reference a variable from **child-component-2**.

how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.